# Fetch data from API CLEARBIT with GOOGLE APP SCRIPTS CANNOT READ PROPERTIES DOMAIN

Tags: url, google-sheets-api

I am using the following code from Google sheet to get site URL.

```
function FETCH(url) {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
    var out = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    return out[0][domain];
}
```

It's gives me the following error:

> "Cannot read properties or undefined (reading 'domain')
> (Line 9).

I'd like to see the website URL in the cells.

And if possible, can I have a script to open websites at once once I select some of the cells?